# Trouble installing SUMO 0.30.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 from source code

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, omnet++, veins, sumo

I need to install SUMO 0.30.0 to be used with the VEINS_INET subproject in veins 4.6. I have tried following the instructions here and suggestions from forums but haven't had any luck being able to install sumo. I run ./configure (trying various tool/library options) then run sudo make but all I get is target marouter failed or nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am' 'install-data-am'.

Does anyone know how to install sumo-0.30.0 from source and/or make the veins_inet subproject work with the latest version of sumo-0.32.0?

Comment: For those that are experiencing a similar issue with installing SUMO, I solved it by following the instructions at the bottom of the page for Ubuntu 14.04  [link](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/userdoc/Installing/Linux_Build_Libraries.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run `sudo make`.

Don't run `sudo make`.

---

Your problem is probably related to a dependency/packaging change in 16.04, which is explicitly pointed out in the [veins tutorial](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/):

> Note that Ubuntu 16.04 no longer includes libproj0; this can be worked around by temporarily adding the packet repository of, e.g., Ubuntu Vivid when installing this package.

Short answer: Unfortunately this means that long-term, you're going to either have to package SUMO yourself, use the versions someone else compiled (see [this launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~sumo/+archive/ubuntu/stable) for example) or rely on an old version.

---

Long answer:
In general, I would recommend building SUMO from source by building its' dependencies from source, since I've encountered this problem on various distributions. In particular, the fox, proj and gdal libraries tend to be packaged in different versions, and along with changes in the SUMO source code. I currently use [this script](https://gitlab-vs.informatik.uni-ulm.de/snippets/3) (with the package versions downloaded) to compile SUMO -- but this is for 0.30.0, and it breaks if any of the referenced source packages are moved (which happens quite often). My general recommendation would be to either use a completely isolated version of SUMO (i.e., compiling by hand as much as possible) or relying on a pre-packaged version (see above), as long as that version is recent enough to work with VEINS.